# How to get a setup file in Visual Studio2012 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am contesting for a competition and they asked to create a app in Windows 8. So I started doing in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate(Windows Store) and I have almost completed my app.When I asked for submission, they are asking only to send a setup file and not to upload in store. When I double clicked the .exe file it is showing that it runs only in the contest of an app container. What is app container? Is it possible to generate set up file with  Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate(Windows Store)?

Comment: There's no mechanism to create "setup files" for a Store app.  The only valid way to deploy them is through the Store.  And there's no way for them to run your app by running a file that you provide to them, the "app container" prevents it from running without a valid Store key.  Impossible to guess what they might mean with that, clearly you ought to contact somebody that's part of the group that supports the competition.  You won't find him here.  Do consider the possibility that this is fake.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to submit this to the Windows Store or to the competition? And what sort of app is this?